# Laravel + Inertia SSR how to change default port? Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::13714

Tags: node.js, laravel, server-side-rendering, pm2, inertiajs

So I have a production site and a staging site. Both are on Laravel and uses Server-Side Rendering (SSR) + Node. The server is Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS. I use PM2 as the production process manager for node.js. When I run
`pm2 start /var/www/example.com/public/build/server/ssr.mjs --name ssr_example --watch` it works:

```
┌─────┬──────────────────────────┬─────────────┬─────────┬─────────┬──────────┬────────┬──────┬───────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┐
│ id  │ name                     │ namespace   │ version │ mode    │ pid      │ uptime │ ↺    │ status    │ cpu      │ mem      │ user     │ watching │
├─────┼──────────────────────────┼─────────────┼─────────┼─────────┼──────────┼────────┼──────┼───────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┤
│ 0   │ ssr_example              │ default     │ N/A     │ fork    │ 168259   │ 50s    │ 0    │ online    │ 0%       │ 65.9mb   │ user     │ enabled  │
└─────┴──────────────────────────┴─────────────┴─────────┴─────────┴──────────┴────────┴──────┴───────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┘
```

But when I want to do the same for the staging version of the website `pm2 start /var/www/staging.example.com/public/build/server/ssr.mjs --name ssr_staging_example --watch` I got this:

```
┌─────┬──────────────────────────┬─────────────┬─────────┬─────────┬──────────┬────────┬──────┬───────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┐
│ id  │ name                     │ namespace   │ version │ mode    │ pid      │ uptime │ ↺    │ status    │ cpu      │ mem      │ user     │ watching │
├─────┼──────────────────────────┼─────────────┼─────────┼─────────┼──────────┼────────┼──────┼───────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┤
│ 0   │ ssr_example              │ default     │ N/A     │ fork    │ 168259   │ 59s    │ 0    │ online    │ 0%       │ 65.1mb   │ user     │ enabled  │
│ 1   │ ssr_staging_example      │ default     │ N/A     │ fork    │ 0        │ 0      │ 15   │ errored   │ 0%       │ 0b       │ user     │ enabled  │
└─────┴──────────────────────────┴─────────────┴─────────┴─────────┴──────────┴────────┴──────┴───────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┘
```

When I look at the log files `pm2 logs` it shows:

```
1|ssr_stag |     at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (node:net:1380:16)
1|ssr_stag |     at listenInCluster (node:net:1428:12)
1|ssr_stag |     at Server.listen (node:net:1516:7)
1|ssr_stag |     at Object._default [as default] (/var/www/staging.example.com/node_modules/@inertiajs/server/lib/index.js:52:6)
1|ssr_stag |     at file:///var/www/staging.example.com/public/build/server/ssr.mjs:617:21
1|ssr_stag |     at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:198:25)
1|ssr_stag |     at async Promise.all (index 0)
1|ssr_stag |     at async ESMLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:409:24)
1|ssr_witt |     at async importModuleDynamicallyWrapper (node:internal/vm/module:435:15) {
1|ssr_stag |   code: 'EADDRINUSE',
1|ssr_stag |   errno: -98,
1|ssr_stag |   syscall: 'listen',
1|ssr_stag |   address: '::',
1|ssr_stag |   port: 13714
1|ssr_stag | }
PM2        | App [ssr_staging_example:1] exited with code [1] via signal [SIGINT]
PM2        | Script /var/www/staging.example.com/public/build/server/ssr.mjs had too many unstable restarts (16). Stopped. "errored"
```

I know it is beceause both are using the same port so I went to `config/inertia.php` and changed the default port, 13714, to 13715

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Server Side Rendering
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | These options configures if and how Inertia uses Server Side Rendering
    | to pre-render the initial visits made to your application's pages.
    |
    | Do note that enabling these options will NOT automatically make SSR work,
    | as a separate rendering service needs to be available. To learn more,
    | please visit https://inertiajs.com/server-side-rendering
    |
    */

    'ssr' => [

        'enabled' => true,

        'url' => 'http://127.0.0.1:13715/render',

    ],
...
...
...
```

But it still doesn't work and I keep getting the same errors. Should I change the port somewhere else, in another (config) file? Or am I doing it wrong? Is there another approach?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue today and I found a solution.

Basically you'll have to change the port both for the SSR server (which is configured when running `npm run build`) and the Laravel runtime. You did the latter in the config file. In order to do the former, pass the port as a second parameter to the `createServer()` in the `ssr.js` file. For example, put 8080 as port:

```js
createServer(page =>
  createInertiaApp({
    // Config here
  }),
  8080
)
```

After the change, you'll have to run `npm run build` to make the SSR server actually start on 8080. Also make sure the port in `config/inertia.php` matches.

I wrote a complete explanation [here](https://dev.to/moay/laravel-inertiajs-running-ssr-on-a-different-port-than-13714-hnj).

Even with the port setup in both the `config/inertia.php` and the `ssr.js`, keep in mind that the port for the SSR server is baked into the build when running `npm run build`. So just setting the port at runtime will not change the actual port the server runs on as long as you do not recreate the production build.