# Running php artisan start-ssr for two sites in same server

Tags: laravel, server-side-rendering, digital-ocean, inertiajs

I have two applications that I have deployed to Digital Ocean using Laravel Forge.
Both is building using Laravel, Vue, Inertia, Tailwindcss Stack. (inertia 1.0)
When I try to start daemon for starting SSR for both server... the port seems to conflict and does not run the daemon as expected. If there is only one site.. everything works perfectly.

What is the issues.. and what is the right way of doing it.

Also another issue is the when I enter  website2.com on browers it automatically redirects to website1.com. Both are on the same digital ocean droplet. But works good when I type the full url https://website2.com

Comment: You should ask your question on https://serverfault.com/ as your question is more related to your server configuration than anything else.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel + Inertia SSR how to change default port? Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::13714](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75346573/laravel-inertia-ssr-how-to-change-default-port-error-listen-eaddrinuse-addr)

Answer (score 1):

This happens because inertia SSR is trying to run all instances on the same default port 13714.

In your /resources/js/ssr.js under createServer method put different ports for each application.